# Switch to iframe with phantom.js

Tags: iframe, phantomjs

I would like to switch to an iframe using pure phantom.js code

Here is my first attempt

```js
var page = new WebPage();
var url = 'http://www.theurltofectch'
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if ('success' !== status) {
        console.log("Error");
    } else {
        page.switchToFrame("thenameoftheiframe");
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

It produces only the source code of the main page. Any idea ?

Notice that the iframe domain is different from the main page domain.

Comment: 1. have you tried calling `page.render()` before switching and after switching to see what images are produced? 2. are you confident `thenameofhteiframe` is actually present in the loaded URL?

Answer (score 2):

Please give this a try I believe it may be an async issues meaning the iframe is not present when trying to access it. I received the below snippet from another post.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    testindex = 0,
    loadInProgress = false;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

/*
page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
  console.log('Trying to navigate to: ' + url);
  console.log('Caused by: ' + type);
  console.log('Will actually navigate: ' + willNavigate);
  console.log('Sent from the page\'s main frame: ' + main);
};
*/


/*
  The steps array represents a finite set of steps in order to perform the unit test
*/

var steps = [
  function() {
    //Load Login Page
    page.open("https://www.yourpage.com");
  },
  function() {
    //access your iframe here
    page.evaluate(function() {


    });
  }, 
  function() {
   //any other step you want 
    page.evaluate(function() {



    });
  }, 
  function() {
    // Output content of page to stdout after form has been submitted
    page.evaluate(function() {
      //console.log(document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].outerHTML);
    });

    //render a test image to see if login passed
    page.render('test.png');

  }
];


interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] === "function") {
    console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] !== "function") {
    console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
console.log(page.content);
```

with

```
console.log(page.frameContent);
```

Should return the contents of the frame phantomjs switched to.

If the iframe is from another domain you may need to add the --web-security=no option like this:

```
phantomjs --web-security=no myscript.js
```

As an additional information, what xMythicx said could be true. Some iframes are rendered via Javascript after page finishes loading. If the iframe contents are empty, then you will need to wait for all resources to finish loading, before you start grabbing stuff from the page. But this is another issue, if you need an answer on this, I suggest you ask a new question about it, and I will answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem for iframes and

> phantomjs --web-security=no

helped in my case :]